# Unable to remove substring from main string having number of double quotes in c#

Tags: c#

I have following main string and I'm trying to remove the highlighted part from main string.

[image]

Following is the code that I'm using. I used a **slash** and **additional double quotes** with each double quote, but no luck :(

```
string a = @""" &amp; IIF(Parameters!RoleID.Value = 4,""";
string b = "\", \"\") &amp; \"";
outputString = outputString.Replace(a, " ");
outputString = outputString.Replace(b, " ");
```

Any idea, what will help? TIA!!

Comment: Why do you have HTML escape characters in the string?

Comment: Why did you post an image instead of the text itself?  That is not helpful.

Comment: Looks like vb code?  similar c# code for that is `booleantest ? "thetrue" : "";` and the `&` adds further emphasis to this...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to escape `&` as `&amp;`.

```
string a = @""" & IIF(Parameters!RoleID.Value = 4,""";
string b = "\", \"\") & \"";
```